# enum export in types.d.ts file drop error

Tags: typescript, next.js, enums, export

I use NextJS and I want export enum in types.d.ts. I get Module not found: Can't resolve '@/types'. Other exports works properly.

My tsconfig.json is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    ".next/types/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

The types.d.ts looks like this:

```
export enum AddressRestrictionType {
    None = "None",
    Blacklist = "Blacklist",
    Whitelist = "Whitelist",
}

export interface AddressRestrictions {
    uuid: string | null
    restrictionType: AddressRestrictionType
    targetIpv4: string
    targetIpv6: string
    targetTenants?: Tenant[]
    targetUsers?: IPDefenseUser[]
    targetUserGroups?: IPDefenseUserGroup[]
}
```

[image: Error message]

I need import enum into page.tsx for this reason:

```
const schema = z.object({
    restrictionType: z.enum([AddressRestrictionType.Blacklist, AddressRestrictionType.Whitelist, AddressRestrictionType.None]),
    addressIpv4: z.string().ip("v4"),
    addressIpv6: z.string().ip("v6"),
})
```

The simple interface export doesn't drop error when I load the page. And it happend only runtime, not compile time. Please help me find out how can I export enum type.

Comment: https://dev.to/zapkub/how-to-proper-use-ambient-enum-from-definition-file-5ddg

Comment: Rename `types.d.ts` -> `types.ts`. Why? Because declaration files do not emit any JavaScript.